# PouchDB bulkdocs doesn't re-add document with {new_edits:false} if it was deleted before

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

A local PouchDB is in sync with a remote Couch. The remote has validations which throw unauthorized errors based on some rules. When a `denied` event occurs, I have written the below code to fetch the remote document and replicate it locally, in order to revert the local doc changes back to how they are on the server -

```
function processUnauthorizedError(err, self) {
  const { doc: { error, id } = {} } = err;
  if (error !== "unauthorized") {
    return;
  }

  // Replace/insert remote doc into local
  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/34570061/2790937
  return self.remoteDB.get(id, {revs: true})
    .then(doc => {
      Logger.log({doc});
      return self.localDB.bulkDocs([doc], {new_edits: false})
    })
    .then((result) => {
      Logger.log({result}); // Empty array, see https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/5775
      return notifyUnauthorized(id, self)
    })
}
```

This strategy is based on this suggestion - https://stackoverflow.com/a/34570061/2790937.
However, if the document was deleted locally, then the localdb `bulkDocs` operation doesn't insert it back. It completes with no errors and returns empty array, which is expected per this issue - https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/5775. To confirm that the document isn't inserted, I did a subsequent `allDocs` as well as a `get` on local.

Any suggestions?

The code is running in latest Chrome (81) and using latest PouchDB (pouchdb-browser) 7.1.1.